# Carryback losses from NOL, does the government give you refunds for prior tax years?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, losses

In the concept of carryback losses from Net Operating Losses (NOL), does the IRS go back to old prior year tax filings and give you a refund on them?

If so, that is awesome! What does the process really look like?

Comment: Unless you are in a position that lets you file amended returns, no. At best, you might be able to use losses to offset future gains.

Comment: @keshlam and what position would that be? For example, in 2009 when Congress temporarily extended carryback NOLs 5 years and lost 36 billion usd doing so, doesn't that imply that all entities (including individuals) were in a position to file amended returns if they had a loss from an activity they intended to make money from?

Comment: You can file amended returns if you discover that your previous return was in error.  Not otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you can carry it back to a previous year, which would involve filing an amended return for that year. You should probably discuss this with a CPA though.

Comment: @pacoverflow thats fine, you can submit that as an answer if you'd like